# On existence of certain integers?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given large $t$ are there integers $t<A,B,m,n,m',n'<2t<t^2/2<|n'A-mB|,|-m'A+nB|$ with $mn'-m'n=AB$, $m+m'$ $=n+n'=A+B$ and $gcd(A,B)=$ $gcd(n'A-mB,-m'A+nB)= gcd((n'A-mB)(-m'A+nB),(A+B))=\pm1$?

$mn'-m'n=AB$, $m+m'=n+n'=A+B\implies m(A+B-n)-(A+B-m)n=AB$ $\implies (m-n)(A+B)=AB$.

Comment: This is quite a collection of conditions - where'd you come by this question? Is there any particular motivation?

Comment: I want to partition $A+B$ with some conditions at the same time force linear algebraic conditions.